# How does the VIsual Studio watch window gets the value for a variable?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch

Lets say I have a variable x of type ABC instantiated. 
When I see the value of x it shows me the value from the x.ToString() method.

Where else the value displayed in the value column could come from?

Any help appreciated,

Thanks,

Dattebayo

Comment: Apparently, you correctly answered your own question: The watch window gets the value of a variable by calling its `ToString` method. So, what's your *actual* question?

Comment: Is there any other way from which the ToString() could get overridden and some wrong value would get displayed. (like an attribute on the class or something that could override the value being displayed in the value column of the watch window?)

Comment: I found an something that could override the display value.
to use an attribute on the type DebuggerDisplayAttribute.

Are there any other places where the value is retrieved for an item being watched in Watch window?

Answer (score 3):

The text you see under the Value column in the Watch window could come from one of three sources.

1. The object's ToString() method, as you've mentioned
2. A [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) on the type ABC, which tells the debugger how to present it to the user.
3. If your "ABC" class is decorated with a [DebuggerTypeProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx) attribute, you would see either the .ToString or the DebuggerDisplay string that the proxy type has.

To the best of my knowledge, those are the only three options.